# Can't get Google App Engine OAuth2-sample (for Python) to work - 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api, sample

I need to use OAuth2 so I wish to develop through App Engine and Python since Google offers sample-code that should make the process easy:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list

It should be simple; just download the files, set the application name in app.yaml and the id/secret in the client_secrets.json. Then run/upload through Google App Engine Launcher.

However, I get the *Error 400:*  **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.**
The redirect URI in the request: *{localhost or appspot.com}*/oauth2callback did not match a registered redirect URI.

**Request Details**

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri={local/appspot}/oauth2callback
state={local/appspot}/:gP-pigwbwB3IBwMjafPlPToxNDE0NTA4ODYy
client_id={id-stuff}.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

I doubt that the problem lies in the code (since it's a working sample), but what more can it be, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the API Console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

In your project, check the API Access settings and make sure that URL is one of the Redirect URIs. If not, add it.

Comment: That gave me a new error. One step closer, thanks!